# processing huge files multiple times in JAVA

Tags: java, file, java-io

I have a file A which contains some records around 40Millon. I have another file B which contains some records around 70Millon. Now i have to iterate over file A, for each record search if there is entry in file B. If so then write the entry in file C.

Please suggest ideas on how to achieve this without bumping memory and with minimum time. I have already tried apache lucene, but it had an additional overhead of creating index, since file B with 70million records is going to change daily (i.e. we get this file from an external system) it is very overkill to recreate indexes daily

Answer (score 4):

Pull the data into mysql or postgres as a table.  Index fields of interest and do a join.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Chronicle Map.

You should be able to load 70 million records in a few seconds to minutes depending on the size of the records. You can update the records in real time if you need to.

As Chronicle Map is persisted and off heap you can do this off line or in another process if this helps.

Or you could use a database, it shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes to bulk load such a table.

Answer (score 1):

If a database is not an option, I have an idea:

**Preprocess your second file**: Grab it and sort it (alphabetically):

```
Anna
Aqua
Claire
Jeremy
Joseph
Vill
```

Now create a file that maps each alphabet character to the line number where it is used as the starting character of a name:

```
A,0
C,2
J,3
V,5
```

The previous steps are called **preprocessing** and you should do them before compiling your program. Obviously sorting such a huge file will take a lot of time, but your deployed program will be a lot faster thanks to it if you use this method:

When you are iterating over your first file, suppose you find `Joseph`. What you do is grab the first character `J` and then use the mapping to determine the first line number this character is used. The mapping will yield `3` and therefore you will iterate the second file to such line number. This saves a lot of time because you will be able to skip using `equals()` on several lines that clearly do not meet your search criteria. To find `Joseph` you will only need to check for `Jeremy` and then `Joseph`.

Now that you understand this technique, you can make it a lot more efficient by using **two** levels instead: for each character in the alphabet, create another mapping for each character of the alphabet. In the case of `J`, it would be

```
JE,3
JO,4
```

Since you are looking for `Joseph`, you will easily determine that the line number to start looking for it is the fourth one, thus skipping even more comparisons.

You can do this on more levels: three, four, etc... It's up to you to determine which one is the most optimal in your case. Mappings don't consume much space, and they will save you a lot of time by skipping over unnecessary entries.

The obvious drawback is that preprocessing a file with 70 million entries is very exhaustive - but this is something that your end-users will not have to experience.

That's one way to do it.

**Note**: You will still need to iterate every line of the second file to reach the desired line number. The point is that you won't need to perform comparisons of any sort - and you will see that this is will save you a lot of processing time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have enough memory to load the data, and don't have a database handy for indexing, your best bet is to use a [sort-merge join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join).

In essence, sort both files by the join/lookup criteria, then read the files in parallel (the "merge").